# Gradle Sync Warning - Manifest merger failed - play-services-wearable

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I get following error message after gradle sync:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:percent:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.
```

In my wear app I have this dependency who throws the error:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
```

If I deactivate it the gradle sync is working.

So far as I know this is the latest version. Can anyone help how I can fix that?

Android Wear app dependencies:

```
compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
```

Comment: set `26.1.0` instead of `27.1.1` .

Comment: `15.0.1` is working fine with `27.0.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0` depends on support library **26.0.2**!
See here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.support/wearable/2.3.0!

The `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1` depends on support library **26.1.0**!
See here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1!

I have solved it by adding this to the manifest file:

```
<meta-data
      tools:replace="android:value"
      android:name="android.support.VERSION"
      android:value="26.1.0" />
```

But it is not ideal because you have to change or remove this if you add a higher library version.
If you forget it you still use 26.1.0 instead of the new version.

A real solution has to be coming from Google that a newer version of `com.google.android.support:wearable` should uses dependency 26.1.0 instead of 26.0.2!

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

try the android studio suggestion

`Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.`

And if that does not work use `26.1.0`
`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the error by overriding the conflicted library. `play-services-wearable:15.0.1` library looks like using `com.android.support:percent:26.0.2` which is also included in `com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0`. Try adding the `support:percent` library to your dependencies block to something like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

    ...
}
```